# How Can You Remove An Edit?

Tags: support

First off, why would two different reviewers approve this anonymous edit?

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/posts/83273/revisions

All they added is the word "cactus" at the end of the question...

Seems we need more proofreading and less blind clicking...

Also, can this approval be reverted? Does the "rollback" link remove the erroneously approved edit?

Answer (score 4):

1) Sometimes approvers aren't that careful as they should be. That's sad, but no edit is permanent that it can't be rollbacked.

2) Yes the rollback will get your original post back in order as version 3 in this case. And at your first rollback, you'll get the [cleanup](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/badges/4/cleanup) bronze badge :-)